# How to allow iPad app to communicate with local server on Windows 8 notebook

Tags: ios, ipad, webserver, windows-8.1

I have a local web server that I run using the startServer.bat command through Maven using a notebook running Windows 8.1. There is also an app on the iPad which I installed using TestFlight that needs to communicate with this server. I make use of an Android tablet as a mobile hotspot for Internet access. The port used for the local server is 8080.

Ever since I have attempted to log in to the app it gives an error:
"We were unable to communicate with the server, please check your connection and try again."

I have added rules for the Firewall, disabled the Firewall and also any security on the notebook. When I attempt to log in, there are items that are logged in the cmd where I can see the information is being retrieved from the app i.e. the username and password. BUT, it almost seems as though information is not being sent back to the app i.e. login was successful you may now carry on. I have also read about Windows 8.1 blocking Metro apps, could there be something similar happening here?

I have ensured that the IP is static on the notebook, that the devices use the same network, and have even looked at using proxies - I have tried using Charles Proxy and CCProxy, but they use too much memory and then the build fails due to timeout so I can't test anything anyway. When I go to the IP of the server (i.e. xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080) in Safari it does connect (although I cannot confirm whether it is behaving 100%), but the iPad app has never successfully logged in. The error always shows once this line is logged:
[image]

Can someone please assist me with this issue, or at least direct me to what I can have a look at on either how to set this up correctly (so that I can check what I have done) or how to overcome this issue.

EDIT: I only have access to the app through Test Flight, but I have confirmed with the head developer that App Transport Security has already been taken into account on the app side. I now feel more than ever that something is blocking the outgoing communication on the Windows side. If I open something like the enable appcontainer loopback program an error is displayed saying that the appcontainer info cannot be gathered and asks if the firewall is on - which it definitely isn't. Do you perhaps know what would be causing this? Would an upgrade to Windows 10 perhaps help?

Comment: To see if there is blocking outside the app level, set up a simple test page on the win8 machine and then try to open it from the iPad with a browser. If that works, confirm the cut process with something like Postman on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you're getting blocked by App Transport Security, which came in with iOS 9.  Try adding the proper exceptions to your iPad app's Info.plist file.

To start with, just try doing adding this key / value pair:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

And see if things work.  If you want to release this app to the public, I'd recommend using a domain-based exception.  [More information can be found in this tutorial](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/).

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks so much for your answer. I only have access to the app through Test Flight, but I have confirmed with the head developer that this has already been taken into account on the app side. I now feel more than ever that something is blocking the outgoing communication on the Windows side. If I open something like the enable appcontainer loopback program an error is displayed saying that the appcontainer info cannot be gathered and asks if the firewall is on - which it definitely isn't. Do you perhaps know what would be causing this? Would an upgrade to Windows 10 perhaps help?

Comment: Firewall issues cause such problems. While developing socket based android app same issue was encountered where android device was sending data to emulator but data from emulator was not getting transferred to the android device. Turned out it was caused due to firewall on windows machine (which was hosting emulator). Turning firewall off helped for us.

Comment: Hi The Rohan Sanap, as far as I can see the Firewall is off...I wish I could say that that was the issue. Been sitting with this issue for at least a week and I don't know what the cause could be. I see in the Task Manager that the Windows Defender Service is running (which I am unable to stop) but the Real-time Protection has been switched off in the Security Center - could this service have an effect?